# Add new row in entity framework results in duplicate rows in grid

Tags: c#, entity-framework, devexpress

I am currently trying to figure out the correct way to handle adding a new row to a DevExpress grid using EF6.1 (it should be noted that it is based on ObjectContext, not DbContext).

The problem I am having is I am getting a duplicate row on the grid control, and seemingly in the datasource as well.

The InitNewRow event code of interest is shown below.

```
    private void ItemsGridView_InitNewRow(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.InitNewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        Log.DebugFormat("INITNEWROW RowHandle = {0} ColumnName = {1} ColumnValue = {2} IsNewRow {3} Grid Rows {4} Datasource Rows {5} Data Row Count {6}", 
            e.RowHandle, 
            ItemsGridView.FocusedColumn == null ? "NULL" : ItemsGridView.FocusedColumn.Name, 
            ItemsGridView.FocusedValue == null ? "NULL" : ItemsGridView.FocusedValue.ToString(),
            ItemsGridView.IsNewItemRow(e.RowHandle),
            ItemsGridView.RowCount,
            (dgItems.DataSource as BindingSource).List.Count,
            ItemsGridView.DataRowCount);

        Log.InfoFormat("Entering gvItems_InitNewRow {0}:{1}", e.RowHandle, ItemsGridView.FocusedRowHandle);
        Debug.Assert(e.RowHandle == ItemsGridView.FocusedRowHandle);
        if (ItemsGridView.IsNewItemRow(e.RowHandle))
        {
            var bindingSource = dgItems.DataSource as BindingSource;
            var item = bindingSource.Current as Item;

            // THIS NEXT LINE CAUSES THE ADDITION OF A NEW ROW IN THE GRID AND THE DATASOURCE
            item.Order = Context.Orders.Where(o => o.OrderID == OrderID).FirstOrDefault();

            dgItems.RefreshDataSource();
            Log.DebugFormat("INITNEWROW RowHandle = {0} ColumnName = {1} ColumnValue = {2} IsNewRow {3} Grid Rows {4} Datasource Rows {5} Data Row Count {6}",
                e.RowHandle,
                ItemsGridView.FocusedColumn == null ? "NULL" : ItemsGridView.FocusedColumn.Name,
                ItemsGridView.FocusedValue == null ? "NULL" : ItemsGridView.FocusedValue.ToString(),
                ItemsGridView.IsNewItemRow(e.RowHandle),
                ItemsGridView.RowCount,
                (dgItems.DataSource as BindingSource).List.Count,
                ItemsGridView.DataRowCount);
```

This code produces the following trace

```
>     2015-02-08 16:10:24,171 [1] DEBUG NOES.Frm.OrdersDE INITNEWROW RowHandle = -2147483647 ColumnName = colProductID ColumnValue = NULL
> IsNewRow True Grid Rows 0 Datasource Rows 1 Data Row Count 0
>     
>     2015-02-08 16:10:24,171 [1] INFO  NOES.Frm.OrdersDE Entering gvItems_InitNewRow -2147483647:-2147483647
>     
>     2015-02-08 16:10:24,171 [1] INFO  NOES.Frm.OrdersDE ] NOES.Frm.OrdersDE::get_Context() executed in 0 milliseconds
>     
>     2015-02-08 16:10:24,179 [1] INFO  NOES.Frm.OrdersDE ] NOES.Frm.OrdersDE::get_OrderID() executed in 0 milliseconds
>     
>     2015-02-08 16:10:24,265 [1] INFO  NOES.Frm.OrdersDE ] NOES.Frm.OrdersDE::ItemsGridView_CalcPreviewText(Object
> sender,CalcPreviewTextEventArgs e) executed in 7 milliseconds
>     
>     2015-02-08 16:10:24,268 [1] INFO  NOES.Frm.OrdersDE ] NOES.Frm.OrdersDE::ItemsGridView_CalcPreviewText(Object
> sender,CalcPreviewTextEventArgs e) executed in 0 milliseconds
>     
>     2015-02-08 16:10:24,269 [1] INFO  NOES.Frm.OrdersDE ] NOES.Frm.OrdersDE::ItemsGridView_CalcPreviewText(Object
> sender,CalcPreviewTextEventArgs e) executed in 0 milliseconds
>     
>     2015-02-08 16:10:24,319 [1] DEBUG NOES.Frm.OrdersDE INITNEWROW RowHandle = -2147483647 ColumnName = colProductID ColumnValue = NULL
> IsNewRow True Grid Rows 1 Datasource Rows 2 Data Row Count 1
>     
>     2015-02-08 16:10:24,328 [1] INFO  NOES.Frm.OrdersDE ] NOES.Frm.OrdersDE::get_LastProduct() executed in 0 milliseconds
>     
>     2015-02-08 16:10:24,330 [1] INFO  NOES.Frm.OrdersDE ] NOES.Frm.OrdersDE::ItemsGridView_InitNewRow(Object
> sender,InitNewRowEventArgs e) executed in 160 milliseconds
```

As can be seen from the trace the row and datasource values increment (using the debugger this is isolated to the items.Order = line.

The Order contains a list of items which the datasource is initialised as :

```
        this.OrderBindingSource.DataSource = CurrentOrder;

        dgItems.DataMember = null;
        var itemsBindingSource = new BindingSource(CurrentOrder, "Items");
        dgItems.DataSource = itemsBindingSource;
```

I originally felt it had something to do with the fact that the created item is a child of the order, however the same effect is seen when adding a reference to a Product to the item (using the same context).  This also causes the same effect of adding the new row to the grid and datasource.

This situation happens whether or not I RefereshDataSource.

Just in case it matters the CurrentOrder property is initialised thus:

```
    private Order CurrentOrder
    {
        get
        {
            if (mCurrentOrder == null)
            {
                DataLoading = true;
                if (OrderID > 0)
                {
                    mCurrentOrder = Context.Orders
                        .Include(Order.EntityDeliveryPath)
                        .Include(Order.EntityItemName)
                        .Include(Order.EntityBatchPath)
                        .Include(Order.EntityItemPunchName)
                        .Include(Order.EntityNoteName)
                        .Include(Order.EntityOrderStatusName)
                        .Include(Order.EntityOrderDeliveryStatus)
                        .Where(o => o.OrderID == OrderID)
                        .Single();
                    OrderID = mCurrentOrder.OrderID;
                    CustomerId = mCurrentOrder.CustomerID??0;
                }
                else
                {
                    mCurrentOrder = Order.CreateOrder(
                        0,  // Will be set on save
                        GetNextOrderNum(), 
                        Context.OrderDeliveryStatus
                            .Where(s => s.Status.Equals("Not Batched"))
                            .Single()
                            .OrderDeliveryStatusID);
                    SetInitialDefaultValues(mCurrentOrder);
                }
                DataLoading = false;
            }
            return mCurrentOrder;
        }
        set
        {
            mCurrentOrder = value;
        }
    }
    private Order mCurrentOrder = null;
```

Saving the context results in a single record being saved however multiple rows appear on the grid.  The second row appears after the end-of-line is reached and the row is validated.

[image: What is on the screen]

I would appreciate it if someone could point out where I have gone wrong, misunderstood how it is supposed to work, etc, so that the second row does not appear on the grid.

It also appears as if the FocusRowHandle is never initialised in this configuration.